# Multiple memory regions mapped to same data

Tags: firmware, memory

I'm analyzing a Seagate HDD that provides a serial boot console that allows reading/writing bytes to memory and setting an address pointer.

There's a block of memory from `0x0` to `0x20000` and then it *repeats* all the way to `0x100000`. This isn't just a copy - if I write a byte to `0x20000` or `0x40000` the data at location `0x0` also changes. At `0x100000` there's another `128k` block that is mirrored over and over until `0x200000`. From `0x400000` the first block of memory is mirrored again and again.

Here's a map:

```
1) 0x000000 - 0x020000
*) (mirrors of block 1)
2) 0x100000 - 0x120000
*) (mirrors of block 2)
3) 0x200000 - 0x300000
4) 0x300000 - 0x400000
*) (mirrors of block 1)
```

The `MCU` is some kind of `ARM` processor. Is this some hardware memory-mapping feature of `ARM`, is it setup by the `OS`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block selection logic just looks at the 4 most significant bits of the address, this is easily implemented by a multiplexer whose outputs feed into the enable pin of each memory chip. An 3 bit multiplexer and an OR gate (if active high) is enough to implement this scheme.

The mirroring within a block happens by not connecting the next set of significant bits to the memory chip, (likely because it just doesn't have the address space).

tl;dr it's a hardware memory map based on how the controller and memory chips are connected on the PCB. And it's something that needs a redesign to adjust.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this is called partial address decoding.